# Mapping between models efficiently

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm a bit new to asp.net core. In this query, it keeps on requerying the db on every node to map from `OrgStructures` to `ToOrgStructureModel` is there a way we can make this more efficient:

This is the area where it keeps on requerying the db: `.Select(org => org.ToOrgStructureModel(db.OrgStructures.Where(s => s.ParentNodeId == org.NodeId).Count() > 0))`

**Whole query:**

```
public virtual IList<OrgStructureModel> GetAll()
{

    using (var db = _context)
    {
        var result = db.OrgStructures
                .Where(e => e.FiscalYear == 19)
                .Select(org => org.ToOrgStructureModel(db.OrgStructures.Where(s => s.ParentNodeId == org.NodeId).Count() > 0))
                .ToList();

        _session.SetObjectAsJson("OrgStructure", result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

**ToOrgStructureModel:**

```
public static OrgStructureModel ToOrgStructureModel(this OrgStructure org, bool hasChildren)
{
    return new OrgStructureModel
    {
        NodeId = org.NodeId,
        ParentNodeId = org.ParentNodeId,
        Name = org.Name,
        DepartmentCode = org.DepartmentCode,
        Acronym = org.Acronym,
        LegacyId = org.LegacyId,
        hasChildren = hasChildren
    };
}
```

**OrgStructureModel:**

```
public class OrgStructureModel
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int? NodeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Acronym { get; set; }

        public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }

        public int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }

        public int? LegacyId { get; set; }

        public int FiscalYear { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }


    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public bool hasChildren { get; set; }
        public OrgStructure ToEntity()
        {
            return new OrgStructure
            {
                NodeId = NodeId,
                Name = Name,
                Acronym = Acronym,
                ParentNodeId = ParentNodeId,
                DepartmentCode = DepartmentCode,
                LegacyId = LegacyId,
                FiscalYear = FiscalYear,
                DepartmentId = DepartmentId
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using custom methods when using Linq-to-sql.

Here's a working alternative that doesn't use `ToOrgStructureModel` method:

```
var result = db.OrgStructures
    .Where(e => e.FiscalYear == 19)
    .Select(org => new OrgStructureModel 
    {
        NodeId = org.NodeId,
        ParentNodeId = org.ParentNodeId,
        Name = org.Name,
        DepartmentCode = org.DepartmentCode,
        Acronym = org.Acronym,
        LegacyId = org.LegacyId,
        // Notice using "Any" method instead of comparing count with 0
        hasChildren = db.OrgStructures.Any(s => s.ParentNodeId == org.NodeId),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This `hasChildren` query will return positive for a root node with no child (though it will work with subsequent child nodes). How to fix this? Here's what I'm seeing https://i.imgur.com/pQq1bOs.png

Comment: I see in your `OrgStructureModel` that `NodeId` is nullable. That might be a reason for `s.ParentNodeId == org.NodeId` being true if `org.NodeId` is null. When does `NodeId` be null? if the node is a root node, and it doesn't have child nodes, does that mean that its `NodeId` is null?

Comment: Basically the `NodeIdWithOutChild` has `NodeId = 463`, and no child has `ParentNodeId = 463` as you can see here: https://i.imgur.com/8m4FECi.png (the reason why you see `ParentNodeId = 1` is because there's another level beyond `463`, but in our use case `463` is our root node)

Comment: I've made the field not nullable `public int NodeId { get; set; }` and the same error still exists, still thinks it hasChildren: https://i.imgur.com/D3Fm730.png

Comment: Ah found the issue, the hasChildren should be like this `s => s.ParentNodeId == s.NodeId`

Comment: If the node with `NodeId = 463` is a root node, then its `ParentNodeId` should be `null` because it has no parent node. Also, in the example you gave, if you didn't find any node that has `ParentNodeId = 463` then `db.OrgStructures.Any(s => s.ParentNodeId == org.NodeId)` should return false because `org.NodeId` would be translated to `463` which is the `NodeId` of the root node. I think the query you gave will always return false, because its trying to find any node that is a parent of itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a lot of queries, essentially for every record that it will pull out it will query one more time for each of them to check for `hasChildren`.

Include the link to the child in your main model (if it's a collection make it a collection),

```
public class OrgStructureModel
{
    ...
    public int? ChildId {get;set;}
    public OrgStructureModel Child {get;set;}
}
```

And then you can create a check in the query

```
     var result = db.OrgStructures
            .Where(e => e.FiscalYear == 19 && e.ChildId != null)
            .Select(org => org.ToOrgStructureModel())
            .ToList();
```

Also read [this](https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/) blog post on projection.

Comment: The `ToOrgStructureModel()` in your query doesn't pass through any required parameters, can you show how it would look if completed, I've provided in the original post what `ToOrgStructureModel` looks like.